# Get elapsed time as a formatted string

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I am looking for the simplest way to calculate and display the execution time of a function in `Qt`. The result should be a `string`/`QString` in the format `mm:ss`.

I know I can get an `int` of milliseconds with `QTime` but is there a built-in function which does the formatting?

Comment: Try to read official documentation, before asking such questions: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtime.html#toString

Comment: I did see that but I don't understand how I will actually taking(start/stopping) the time

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qelapsedtimer.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the elapsed time in milliseconds (`ms`), you can print the time in `mm:ss` format in the following way:

```
QString out = QString("%1:%2").arg( ms / 60000        , 2, 10, QChar('0'))
                              .arg((ms % 60000) / 1000, 2, 10, QChar('0'));
```

Comment: I accepted this answer to early. This doesn't give me the correct format of `mm:ss`. For example if the duration was 7 seconds your code gives me **0:7** instead of **00:07**

Comment: @isADon once again. Before asking such questions - you may read official documentation about string formatting.

Comment: @isADon, I have updated the answer to support the mentioned format.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem in one of my applications. With a small trick it is possible to use the `toString` method in `QTime`. It needs to be considered, that `toString` also takes care of the locale and allows for different time formats. This makes it a non-trivial function to implement.

The following complete code should be enough to explain the basic idea:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTime>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QEventLoop>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    QApplication app(argc, args);
    QTime x;
    x.start();
    QTimer wait;
    QEventLoop e;
    QTimer::singleShot(500, &e, &QEventLoop::quit);
    e.exec();
    QTime y(0, 0);
    qDebug() << x.elapsed();
    y=y.addMSecs(x.elapsed());
    qDebug() << y.toString("mm:ss.zzz");
}
```